# State:not_verified pubsubhubbub

Tags: websub

Why I am [not verified](http://bit.ly/i3P3sb+)? It echoes hub.challenge only but [the state is not verified](http://bit.ly/fwWoyS+).

Answer (score 0):

Does your callback echo the challenge and return a 2XX? it has too, or the subscription will never be confirmed...

Comment: Now it's verified: http://bit.ly/eq7sQE .But the new articles doesn't come to me.

Comment: OK ,I found the core of the problem: http://bit.ly/eIHtSq , http://bit.ly/foiak8
Even if I publish the feed manually ,it doesn't give me any info about it in publisher diagnostics.